# $\int_{0}^{n} 2 ^{[x]} dx = ?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I just started studying definite integrals and I stumbled upon this interesting integral:

$\int_{0}^{n} 2 ^{[x]}  dx $, where ${[x]} $ is the greatest integer less then or equal to x. Any ideas?

Comment: Is $\left[x\right]$ meant to be the greatest integer less than $x$?

Comment: If $[x]$ is the Gauß-bracket, aka floor function, make it a sum. The integrand is constant on each interval $[k,k+1)$.

Comment: @BrianScholl you are right. I will make an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split up the integration area in intervalls of length $1$ and note, that $2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ is constant on each of those intervalls.

Thus

$$\int_0^n 2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1} 2^k\,dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k  = \frac{1-2^n}{1-2} = 2^n-1$$

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your intention is $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$, we can put

$$\int_0^n 2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1} 2^k\;dx$$

and remember:

$$\int a^xdx=\frac1{\log a}a^x+C\;,\;\;a>0$$